# Can apache expose the ldap group used to authenticate to a php application?

Tags: php, ldap, apache-2.4, mod-auth-ldap

I have a LAMP server setup using Apache2, mod_php, and mod_authnz_ldap to authenticate to Active Directory. This hosts a lightweight php application where users enter and manipulate data. Access is based on 'require ldap-group ...' directives, and a number of groups are valid.

We now need to add access for an additional group, but their access must be 'read-only'. In this case, we need to determine at the application level what group a user is in, and disable certain functions based on that group membership. The application is php, so something php can access easily is ideal.

### The ideal solution:

The AD group name apache has used to grant access can easily be exposed to the application, similar to how `$_SERVER['AUTHENTICATE_SAMACCOUNTNAME']` is.

### Solutions I'd like to avoid:

#### 1. Accessing ldap through a php module

We are already authenticating via apache, so this creates unnecessary duplication, extra work to implement, and additional maintenance overhead (one more bind URL to change). Doable, but it's a pain.

#### 2. Modifying the AuthLDAPURL

Again, requires we deviate from our standards just for this host, and maintain that going forward. Doable, but a slightly smaller pain. Adding other ldap directives or vhost changes however, would be trivial to do.

#### 3. Adding a duplicate Vhost with more limited access

This actually seems like the best idea, however it would require we publish a new URL for the new group, which is a bad user experience and might possibly be rejected flat-out.

#### 4. SQL based authentication

So much extra overhead that it's completely not viable for this case. (And technically wouldn't answer the question anyway).

Comment: Did "memberof" as suggested by @Nathan-Ladwig work for you? Do you have an example you can share of an AuthLDAPURL?

Comment: @chrisinmtown This was so long ago. I'm no longer at that job so I can't check and that answer wasn't available then. I think I just created a custom page and applied a more restrictive access rule to that via Apache, per my comment in the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just use SetEnv in apache: 
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html

Then in PHP use getenv() or the $_SERVER[] array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I can see how this would work, but I still don't see _what_ I would use to set the environment variable for apache.

However, this got me thinking, and I can probably just add a rule to the vhost that only allows that authenticated group if they are accessing a specific page (which is already "read-only")

Answer (score 2):

When I use the following line with mod_authz_ldap it passes the uid and memberof variables to PHP:

```
AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://<server>/cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=ipa,dc=domain,dc=tld?uid,memberof?one?"
```

Comment: The "memberof" attribute looks really promising! I guess mod_authnz_ldap should set an environment variable AUTHORIZE_memberof.  What content arrives in that variable?